# Android Login with Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: android, json, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

Hi i am currently doing a project using android with login features online and i am currently using ruby on rails 4

I am currently looking for some helm with some tutorials on how this can be done .

more specifically video tutorials and not just with text based explanations , as i have a hard time studying text based tutorials and most of the result's that  i got from searching online are a bunch of php tutorials with android and just 1 tutorial's from ruby on rails but its 3.+ with it and i need something like the 4.+ something as i am also currently looking and doing some programming with the ruby on rails 4 and have a hard time changing to other versions.

any help will be appreciated and would be of great help

Comment: Mind giving some context?